# c# How to detect if a particular method has overloaded versions?

Tags: c#, reflection

I just need to know if there's a smart way to detect if a particular Type method has overloads or not.

At the moment I'm iterating through methods and searching for `DeclaringType+Name` ambiguity...but I think it's a bit lame :)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can use the object browser in visual studio to peruse your objects and their signatures.

Answer (score 1):

> The overload is what happens when you have two methods with the same name but different signatures.

So if we can the method is `override` by check method name whether more than one.

I would create an extension method `IsOverloads` to make it.

use the `IsOverloads` method need to provide at least two parameter

1. the class `Type`.
2. check method name

Using reflection to gets method information from the class, then check the method name greater than one means the method is overload.

```
public static class Ext {
    public static bool IsOverloads(this Type type,string methodName)
    {
        return IsOverloads(type, methodName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    }

    public static bool IsOverloads(this Type type, 
                                   string methodName, 
                                   BindingFlags flags)
    {
        var info = type.GetMethods(flags);
        return info.Where(o1 => o1.Name == methodName).Count() > 1;
    }
}
```

Here is a simple

```
public class Program
{        
    public void Test() { }  
    public void Test(int a) { }
    public void TestNo(int a) { }

    public static void Main()
    {  

        Console.WriteLine(typeof(Program).IsOverloads("Test")); //True

        Console.WriteLine(typeof(Program).IsOverloads("TestNo")); //false
    }
}
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gCWY1D)

Comment: I think OP was asking for Overloads, not Overrides

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx

Comment: Note this will only work for publicly accessible methods, which may be fine in the scope of the original question.

Comment: @D-Shih I guess then that the only way is counting methods with the same name?No Binding flag or tags?